# How can I choose the correct mechanism for nucleophilic substitution of aryl halides?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, aromatic-compounds, halides

I was reading about nucleophilic substitutions of aryl halides, and there are three different mechanisms discussed, namely the S<sub>N</sub>1, S<sub>N</sub>Ar (addition-elimination), and benzyne (elimination-addition) mechanisms.

However, I am confused as to how to identify which mechanism is operative. How can I tell this from the reaction conditions and reagents?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Before comparing the three main mechanisms, I will first explain why aryl halides typically do not undergo S<sub>N</sub>2-type reactions. Take bromobenzene as a typical example of an aryl halide. A nucleophile, like hydroxide ion, cannot simply displace the bromide from bromobenzene. Quoting from *Organic Chemistry* (1st ed., p 589) by Clayden et al.,

> In the aromatic compound, the C–Br bond is in the plane of the ring as the carbon atom is trigonal. To attack from the back, the nucleophile would have to appear inside the benzene ring and invert the carbon atom in an absurd way. This reaction is not possible!

---

In rare cases, S<sub>N</sub>1 reactions can take place; these characteristically occur when there is an excellent leaving group on the arene. One of the few examples is in the case of an aryldiazonium ion, where the corresponding leaving group is nitrogen gas.

[image: Sample SN1 reaction]

Note that the presence of a diazonium ion does not necessarily imply a S<sub>N</sub>1 mechanism; there are also other possible mechanistic pathways, mainly involving radical chemistry.

---

The next possibility is that of an addition-elimination reaction, commonly termed S<sub>N</sub>Ar. This is made possible by electron-withdrawing groups (e.g. nitro or carbonyl groups) when they are *ortho* and/or *para* to the halogen, as the negative charge in the intermediate can be delocalised into these electron-withdrawing groups:

[image: Sample SNAr mechanism]

---

Finally, the benzyne mechanism. Consider bromobenzene: it cannot undergo S<sub>N</sub>2 reactions (as explained above), S<sub>N</sub>1 reactions (bromide is not a sufficiently good leaving group), or S<sub>N</sub>Ar reactions (no electron-withdrawing group *ortho* or *para* to bromine). However, under strongly basic conditions, it is possible to eliminate HBr by abstracting a proton *ortho* to the halide. Examples of such strong bases include sodium amide (NaNH<sub>2</sub>), LDA/lithium diisopropylamide (LiN*i*-Pr<sub>2</sub>), or potassium *tert*-butoxide (KO*t*-Bu).

[image: Sample benzyne mechanism]

---

To summarise the three categories:

1. If you have a very good leaving group - primarily nitrogen gas - on the aromatic compound, then a S<sub>N</sub>1 mechanism is possible.
2. If you have good electron withdrawing groups *ortho* or *para* to the halide, then it is likely an addition-elimination or S<sub>N</sub>Ar reaction.
3. If the above two are not possible, and if you have an extremely strong base such as NaNH<sub>2</sub> or KO*t*-Bu, then the benzyne mechanism may be applicable.